# Can't ssh to AWS EC2: Identity file not accessible

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I'm unable to ssh to my EC2 server and am getting the error:

```
ssh -i /Users/Skeniver/Keepass/skeniver.pem ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xxx

Identity file /Users/Skeniver/Keepass/skeniver.pem not accessible: No such file or directory
```

The file is definitely in the directory and I've chmod'd the directory to 755 and the file to 600:

```
drwxr-xr-x  14 Skeniver  staff    476 28 Nov  2012 Keepass
-rw-------  1 Skeniver  staff    1696  5 Oct  2012 skeniverkey.pem
```

I'm pretty sure it's a permissions problem, but can't figure out why...

Here is the output of the ssh command using -v, in case it's of any use:

```
Warning: Identity file /Users/Skeniver/Keepass/skeniver.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.xx.xxx [xx.xxx.xx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/Skeniver/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Skeniver/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/Skeniver/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'xx.xxx.xx.xxx' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Skeniver/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/Skeniver/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Skeniver/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Skeniver/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Try swapping the order of the parts, i.e. `ssh user@server.ip.address -i identity_file.pem`

Answer (score 31):

You need the identity file to login to the box. Use the command:

```
ssh -i (identity_file) username@hostname"
```

This worked for me. Write just the filename (without any slashes), unlike Amazon EC2 tutorial which asks you to enter:

```
ssh -i /path/key_pair.pem ec2-user@public_dns_name
```

It worked for me after putting the identity file in the .ssh (hidden) folder on home. To view hidden folders on home, use `ctrl+h`

Answer (score 22):

I had similar issue and found that there was hidden char in command, pasting to plain text editor and copy back helped me.

Answer (score 5):

I was having this same issue. Storing the identity file in my `~/.ssh` directory and running `cd ~/.ssh` before `ssh -i (identity_file) username@hostname` worked. I only ran into the issue when trying to run the ssh command from outside the `~/.ssh` directory. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Depending on system, in Linux you could do `/home/(user)/.ssh/(identify_file)` and run it regardless of current working path.

Comment: @metame so when you say in "Linux" how broad are restricted is your scope? like do you mean in 'nix systems? I ask, because I just had this same issue on os x. I tried sshing with a pem like i 'almost' normally do... however... I wasnt in my home directory. As soon as I switched to my home directory and edited my command to be `ssh -i '.ssh/blah.pem' ..` it worked as usual.

I could have sworn i have done this before... I know that I have used the pem file in all sorts of directories never been a problem. 

So, why does /home/user/.ssh/blah.pem no work but being in the user directory does?

Answer (score 5):

For your case just

just execute the following command to change permission

`sudo chmod 400 /Users/Skeniver/Keepass/skeniver.pem`

and then execute the command that will connect you to EC2

`ssh -i /Users/Skeniver/Keepass/skeniver.pem ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xxx`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and i found that the issue with the file path.
Right click on the your key_pair.pem (identical file) go the properties and copy and now your comment is like

```
ssh -i /path/skeniver.pem user@your_public_ip
```

for example in my case command like

```
ssh -i /home/anil/.ssh/webKey.pem ec2-user@ec2-45-349-50-38.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 1):

`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/public_key_file` solved for me

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you typed the wrong filename. You're specifying the filename `skeniver.pem` in your command, but it looks like your filename is actually `skeniverkey.pem`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons to occurring this error.
1 you are trying to access from whatever path which is not match
2 either you do not have permission to do access
3 if you do not have access to that particular file you can try to change the mode of permission

like the above solution

```
sudo chmod 400 /Users/Skeniver/Keepass/skeniver.pem
```

even if not then you can co-ordinate with the network or your cloud team whoever manage your cloud server

Answer (score 1):

This is weird, but in my case I was copying the command from a slack message and that repeatedly caused this error, even though I met all the above requirements. Typing the whole command without copying anything from clipboard worked for me. Posting this here and I hope this helps someone one day.

Comment: I forgot to add `.pem` at the end while trying to connect to the remote EC2 machine. Please check this carefully.

Answer (score 1):

When connecting from a windows environment what did the trick for me was putting the path in quotation marks `"` as follows:

```
ssh -i "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\XXXX\testing_amazon_linux.pem" ubuntu@XXXX.amazonaws.com
```

I replaced identifiable things with `XXXX` but let the rest in place to improve example clarity.

Answer (score 0):

run the command from .ssh directory i.e/Users//.ssh and then execute the command
ssh -v -i   @

this worked for me after many failed attempt.

note: please make sure .pem file has necessary permission
chmod 400 <.pem file> before executing the command

Answer (score 0):

I got here while solving same or similar problem. After trying a few things this works for me eventually. I am on MacBook Pro and trying to connect to Ec2 Amazon Linux 2 using VSCode Remote SSH.

I have to update this file

> /Users/MrRobot/.ssh/config

There is a config in the file like below.

> IdentityFile xx.pem

I have to update this to full path wherever your id_rsa or pem file is.

> IdentityFile /Users/MrRobot/.ssh/xx.pem

Answer (score 0):

my solution is move it to the path which is all the english chars

(i am a chinese, and use the chinese windows, when i run the command from the path which contains the chinese chars, it will return "Warning: Identity file debao-visa.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.")

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue occurred and the problem was that the file extension was hidden.

So the real filename was `skeniver.pem.txt` instead of `skeniver.pem`

A simple way to determine this is to press tab while typing the filename. So type part of the filename like `skenive` then hit tab, it should print the rest of the file in the terminal and you should see if it has any part after `.pem` like `.pem.txt`.

Try

`ssh -i /Users/Skeniver/Keepass/skeniver.pem.txt ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xxx`

or remove the `.txt` or any other extension from the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different idea, here's what I did. I couldn't upload to a folder, so I put the uploaded folder to “ ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xx.xx:/tmp ” ,then I uploaded successfully and cp the file on the server afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
ssh -i Users/Skeniver/Keepass/skeniver.pem ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

instead of

```
ssh -i **/**Users/Skeniver/Keepass/skeniver.pem ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

Answer (score -2):

You need the identity file to login to the box.
Use the command

```
ssh -i (identity_file) username@hostname
```